# Null Pointer exception in Arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am getting null pointer exception even though I have placed the Null Check:

```
@Override 
    public ArrayList<DataCache> getData()   
    { 
        if(contentOf != null)
        {
            StoreData data = new StoreData(this);
            if(data!=null)
            {
                ArrayList<DataCache> cacheOf = null;
                System.out.println("Size of ContentOf"+contentOf.size());
                for (int i=0;i<contentOf.size();i++)
                {
                    System.out.println("Value of ContentOf"+contentOf.get(i).mFeed);
                    ArrayList<DataCache> cache = contentOf.get(i).mFeed.getData();
                    if (cache != null)
                        cacheOf.add(cache.get(i));
                }
                return cacheOf;
            }
        }
}
```

**Exception:**

```
02-03 10:19:18.770: E/AndroidRuntime(8680): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-03 10:19:18.770: E/AndroidRuntime(8680): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-03 10:19:18.770: E/AndroidRuntime(8680): at 
com.activity.MainFragmentActivity.getData(MainFragmentActivity.java:198)
```

Comment: what is in the line 198?

Comment: Line 198 will be cacheOf.add(cache.get(i));

Comment: Null Pointer exception is at "cacheOf.add(cache.get(i));"

Comment: initialize cacheOf like user @ρяσѕρєя K said will solve your problem!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also need to initialize `cacheOf` ArrayList before Adding elements as:

```
ArrayList<DataCache> cacheOf = new ArrayList<DataCache>(); //initialize here
System.out.println("Size of ContentOf"+contentOf.size());  //This will be zero.
for (int i=0;i<contentOf.size();i++) {
      //..your code here...
    if (cache != null){
       if(i<=cache.size())
         cacheOf.add(cache.get(i));
     }
}
```

Comment: Even after initializing I am getting the same error

Comment: I removed cacheOf = null after initializing and I got the below error:02-03 10:41:53.640: E/AndroidRuntime(9143): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-03 10:41:53.640: E/AndroidRuntime(9143): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
02-03 10:41:53.640: E/AndroidRuntime(9143):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
02-03 10:41:53.640: E/AndroidRuntime(9143):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)

Comment: I changed the condition check to cache.size() >i and it worked. if i=0, size of the cache should be at least 1.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the error?

The key here is:  com.activity.MainFragmentActivity.getData(MainFragmentActivity.java:198)

What line is 198?

I suspect it is either one of these:

```
System.out.println("Value of ContentOf"+contentOf.get(i).mFeed);
ArrayList<DataCache> cache = contentOf.get(i).mFeed.getData();
```

You have memory that is uninitialized.